# How to use Git in my workflow

Tags: php, git, webdav

I'm trying to learn how to use Git in my daily workflow but I'm slightly confused as to how to make it work for me. As a web developer, the way I work is that I have two VPS' - one as a production and the other as a development server. On the development server, I usually create a webdav that points to the source files (located in /home/public_html/dev.domain.co.uk/) and mount it as a local folder on my mac. This way, I can open (or create) the PHP files in my IDE, do what I need to, save the file and then refresh the test link in my browser.

Now, as I say, I would like to start using Git to keep track of all amends I, and my co-workers, make to projects. So my question is how would I do this - would I create a repository on my development server in the public_html folder? And when I clone the repository on the different machines I work on, would I mount the webdav and clone the repository in there? Ideally I want to set up an online repo that myself and co-workers can access.

Any help and/or advice would be much appreciated.

Thanks :)

Comment: check [git flow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/), it's very interesting.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar workflow.  I was using my IDE to edit the files over SSH, effectively using the files directly on a development server.  What I ended up doing was opening a console over SSH to my dev server, and running git there.  I use Bitbucket as a remote, and push/pull from there, keeping all of my changes somewhat centralized.  What I need to push to my production server, I pull from Bitbucket, and then flip a symlink so that all files appear updated instantaneously.

Comment: Sounds interesting...So do you push directly to your production server instead of a development server first?

Comment: @GoonyanHarir, No, absolutely not.  I do my work on a development server.  Only when I'm ready to release, and have done merges to a release branch do I pull code down from Bitbucket to the production server.

Comment: Cool, this is exactly how I'm thinking I should work too. I'm going to do some more reading on Git.

Answer (score 1):

Git is a decentralized version control system, meaning that you do not need to have a "shared" repository. However, when collaborating, especially if you do not work closely with your coworkers, it might be attractive to have a central point with an "official" repository.

Now in your case, if you want to continue working in your WebDAV exported folder on your testing machine, it depends on if you share this folder with coworkers or not. If it's your private working space, create your git repository there and work with it however you like.

To setup a central, "official" repository you push you changes to, you have several choices depending on your infrastructure:

- Use a 3rd party service like GitHub or BitBucket: This is simple to setup and use, but may require subscription fees if you want to keep your repository private.
- Use your development server and setup a clone of your repository in a shared place, either via SSH or WebDAV. This might require more maintenance and you don't get the fancy WebUI of GitHub and the likes.

You might also want to have a look at this article about a [branching model](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) for development.

Comment: We both work remotely and both mount the same WebDAV share as it points to the source files. Forgive me if this sounds silly, but would we both pull the changes from the shared repository onto our local machine, say the desktop, and then copy the files onto the WebDAV?

Comment: @GoonyanHarir no, you just share the git repository. This only works if you do not try to run git commands at the same time though.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a service like http://bitbucket.org.

it's free and it allows to create private and public repositories.

Once you commit changes, simply `push` it to the server (they tell you how to do it), then have your partner to clone that repository and `pull` from it whenever necessary.

Comment: Thanks, I'll be sure to check it out. When my partner clones the repository, is it best if he clones it locally on his Mac, for example, on his desktop, and then copy the files into the mounted webdav folder once he's finished?

Comment: Isn't the point to keep the work synchronized even though you're working on different computers?

Comment: @Truth Maybe some GitHub hardcore fan?